# Most efficient turbine for harnessing energy from bidirectional air flow?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, airflow, turbines, energy-efficiency

I am currently working on designing an oscillating water column as part of a project. In summary:

> OWC are devices with a semi-submerged chamber or hollow open to the
>   sea below, keeping a trapped air pocket above a water column. Waves
>   force the column to act like a piston, moving up and down, forcing the
>   air out of the chamber and back into it. This continuous movement
>   force a bidirectional stream of high-velocity air, which is channelled
>   through a Power-Take-Off (PTO). The PTO system converts the airflow
>   into energy.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillating_water_column

In my case, the PTO system is a turbine, the rotation of which will power a rotary vane pump. 
[image: Number 2 is the pump rotor]
(Number 2 is the pump rotor)

The pump rotor and the turbine would be on the same axis and connected by a rod. In short, the rotation of the turbine would directly power the pump; electricity would not be produced in the process.

I've been searching to see what turbines would be the most efficient, but I haven't found any information. What would be the most efficient turbine for this situation? Is it a Wells Turbine? Something like a bidirectional impulse turbine [image]

or something else?

Comment: Check out a Wells turbine.

Comment: I know what a Wells turbine is. I was wondering whether it is the best turbine design to use for the project.

Comment: You did not mention it... So do a comprison for the types you know about... efficiency, range of flowrate etc

Comment: I did, indeed, mention a Wells turbine in my question. As for " So do a comprison for the types you know about... efficiency, range of flowrate etc", that is exactly my problem and why I have asked this question: I don't know the efficiency of the two designs I mentioned, nor am I knowledgeable about other things that have to be considered.

Comment: So for the Wells turbine that you have researched, what is the blade profile? Was it rated for a particular (minimum) flow?